# Check if file exists remotly in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, cron

I have a bashscript which checks if a file exists on the remote server.
When i execute this bashscript on commandline it works fine and say to me the file exist (as  it should). But when crontab is executing this bashscript it says that the file not exist (although it would exist
).

can anybody help me?

myscript.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if $(sudo ssh -i <path/to/ssh/keys> <user>@<ip> "[[ -f /etc/ssl/file.txt  ]]");then
       echo "exist"
    else
       echo "not exist"
    fi
```

crontab:

```
    */1 * * * * bash /home/user/myscript.sh | mail -s "betreff" user@email.com
```

stderr: (when i run the script on the commandline)

```
    ++ sudo ssh -i <path/to/ssh/keys> <user>@<ip> '[ -f /etc/ssl/file.txt ]'
    + echo exist
    exist
```

stderr: (when i run the script in cron)

```
    ++ sudo ssh -i <path/to/ssh/key> <user>@<ip> '[ -f /etc/ssl/file.txt ]'
    Warning: Identity file /root/.ssh/key/keyfile not accessible: No such file or directory.
    Permission denied, please try again.
    Permission denied, please try again.
    root@<ip>: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Permission of ssh keyfile:

```
    -rw------- 1 root     root     3243 Sep 30 15:34 keyfile
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      741 Sep 30 15:34 keyfile.pub
```

Thanks for helping :D

Comment: Try setting your `PATH` at the top so that `ssh` and `sudo` are on it.

Comment: You can get lot of information by adding 'set -x' to your script. Review/share stderr output.

Comment: Don't use `$( )` here -- it takes the output from `sudo ssh` (there probably isn't any) and tries to run it as a command. It's not a command. Also, `sudo` generally requires interactive authentication, so it won't work in a cron job (unless it's in the root crontab, in which case it's not needed).

Comment: Hello Gordon i've deleted `$( )` and add the line from cronjob to the root cronjob. But the result is the same. The File not exist. @dash-o also the `set -x` command in the script is not usefull on command line it says exitst and in cron it doesn't. :(

Comment: In crontab you forget username for start script. Before "bash" write "root".

Comment: Do you use ssh-keys or write passwords manually?

Comment: Please consider sharing the stderr or running the script under cron with '-x'. The question does not have enough information to replicate the problem. More specified, what is "not found" - the bash script or one of the commands in the script.

Comment: @Šerg i use ssh-keys. @dash-o the stderr when i execute the bashscript on commandline:`++ sudo ssh -i /home/user/sshkey root@<ip> '[ -f /etc/ssl/test.cer ]'
+ echo exist exist` The Problem is when the bashskript is executing by cron it sent me a mail which contains (form tha bash if loop) that the file **not** exist.

Comment: @ThomasE. The '-x' interactive output indicates 'ssh -i', but your cron job does not have a the '-i ...' option. May be the 'ssh' is aliases to 'ssh -i ...' for interactive shell ?

Comment: @dash-o i could restrict my issue. See on the top.

Comment: If the keyfile in '/root/.ssh/key/', from the error message  ' Warning: Identity ... no such fille ...' it looks as if it's not there. Try adding 'ls -l /root/.ssh/key' to the script, and check output from cron. Also, why does the log shows '<path/to/ssh/key>' and not '/root/.ssh/key/keyfile) ? - is this actual output ?

Comment: Hii all, i could find my issue. The reason was, that i used relative paths like `~/.ssh` for my sshkeys after writing down in absolute like `home/user/...` everything works fine. Thanks for helping :)